# How would a rigid disk rotating near speed of light behave?

Tags: special-relativity, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Say you had a perfectly rigid disk so that you can't morph it or bend it. If you were to spin near the center of the disk at near speed of light, the edge of disk would have to be faster but of course not exceed C. However, according to rotational and rigid body dynamics the points on a rigid body must increase in tangential velocity at a rate proportional to the distance away from axis of rotation.

The only way for special relativity to be kept in this spinning disk is if it were for the disk to sort of spiral or curve as you go farther away from the center. But again, this is a rigid disk and that is not possible.

How can special relativity be conserved in this scenario?

Comment: See also [Ehrenfest paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox)

Comment: @JohnRennie "Rigid bodies can't exist" what an anticlimactic answer lol but it's an answer nonetheless. Thanks John.

Comment: You might also be interested to read about [Born rigidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rigidity).